# AWS API gateway Stage name error handling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Consider I have created an API using with AWS API gateway with the following URL

https://0abcgdefg1.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/Employee/.

is it possible to create an error message if the end user tried a nonexisting stage name? For eg

https://0abcgdefg1.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/**Employee1**/

is it possible to give some error information like below?

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Stage name Employee1doesn't exist",
            "type": "InvalidStageError"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No APIGW do not support returning custom error information when stage does not exits.

I am also wondering why you need to return this error message to API user ? can you provide details about your use case ?

Comment: Just checking if this sort of error handling is possible or not? Meanwhile, did you find any documentation regarding this?

Comment: Its not supported - hence not documented.